# Can I import data from one JSON file to another JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 JSON files, for example:
FILE 1

```
{
    "fName": "John Doe",
    "favCategory": "category"
}
```

FILE 2

```
{
    "articleTitle": "The Title",
    "author": <<fName>>
}
```

I want the author key in the second JSON file to have value imported from the first file.

How can I do it? simple import and export doesn't work.

Comment: [You can't](http://json.org/). Unless you use JavaScript to read the one JSON file, parse it, read and parse the second JSON file, update its content, stringify it back to JSON and write it back to the file.

Comment: @str Maybe there is any creative way to do so?

Comment: Any creative way will eventually  do what @str is mentioning in one way or another.

Comment: Agree with the above. Although it should be noted that you don't need to use JavaScript necessarily...almost any programming language will have a library for dealing with JSON these days